# Finding Compitation Errors in JSX

Tags: gulp, reactjs

I created a sample application by using [React.JS Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit). The application runs well. I modified the component code, and seems there are some errors which I can see in the browser console window.

Where can I find the errors generated by the Gulp? I can't debug the code because the module **home.jsx** is not built as part of the built by Gulp. The windows console where the gulp running does not show the error as well.

[image]
[image]

UPDATE:

App.jsx where the Home.jsx is referenced:

```jsx
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var {Routes, Route} = require('react-router');

// Export React so the dev tools can find it
(window !== window.top ? window.top : window).React = React;

React.render(
  <Routes location="history">
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={require('./layouts/Default.jsx')}>
      <Route name="home" path="/" handler={require('./pages/Home.jsx')} />
      <Route name="privacy" handler={require('./pages/Privacy.jsx')} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>,
  document.body
);
```

Comment: Where are you refrencing "./pages/Home.jsx".

Comment: Please see the update in the original question.